# Tracking changes to object structures through SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, sobject, describesobject

I am looking to check whether the object that I queried has changed during the previous access. For example, if a new field was added to the Account field, I would like to alert the user that a new field X was added after the last access. As my access is through SOAP API, I am marshaling the DescribeSObjectResult class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "DSRList")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class DescribeSObjectResults
{
    private List<DescribeSObjectResult> DescribeSObjectResult;

    public List<DescribeSObjectResult> getdsrList()
    {
        return DescribeSObjectResult;
    }

    public void setdsrList(List<DescribeSObjectResult> filtered_dsrList)
    {
        this.DescribeSObjectResult = filtered_dsrList;
    }
}

DescribeSObjectResults dsrs = new DescribeSObjectResults();
            dsrs.setdsrList(filtered_dsrList);
            File dsrFile = new File("file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DescribeSObjectResults.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(dsrs, dsrFile);
```

Storing this info and then tracking change individually. Is this the way to go?